# How can i append an item more than once at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, list, append

I would like to append append an item more than once. e.g

```
listA = ['AS','23','45']
listB = ['TH','67','78']

listB.append(listA.pop()*3)

print(listA)
# ['AS', '23']

print(listB)
#['TH', '67', '78', '454545']
```

on printing listB, it currently gives me the above list
but i want it to give me `# ['TH', '67', '78', '45','45','45']` instead

How can i do this.

Comment: Notice that the `listA.pop()` call returns a _string_, and thus you apply the `*` operator on a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) and repeating not the string returned by `pop()`, but a single-element list:

```
>>> listA = ['AS','23','45']
>>> listB = ['TH','67','78']
>>> listB.extend([listA.pop()]*3)
>>> listB
['TH', '67', '78', '45', '45', '45']
```

Comment: If the number of items is large, you might want to use [itertools.repeat](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

Comment: @jterrace: Probably, or just a `for` loop.